# Geofencing using google maps in laravel

Tags: laravel, google-maps, geolocation

I am creating a laravel based website where i want a feature where some users can create geofence around a point in the map on the page. I have done some reasearch and it seems that only android users can create fences using the geofencing API in google. Has anyone done something like this or has any idea how to do this?

Edit: I want the logged in users to be able to draw on a google map screen a shape which acts as a fence where if a certain vehicle goes in/out the user get some sort of an alert. The vehicle has an IOT device that would tell me the vehicle location. 
Thanks

Comment: could you do something like set the center point of a "map" based on latitude/longitude and then define a radius from that point?  I'm not 100% sure what you are going for as far as the website goes.  A little further explanation may help ouy.

Comment: i think you might use https://github.com/njbarrett/laravel-postgis or see https://medium.com/@brice_hartmann/getting-started-with-geospatial-data-in-laravel-94502dc74d55